# How to swap JSON property with another from variable?

Tags: json, jq

I have two JSON files, A.json and B.json.

A.json

```
{
  "ui": {
    "strings": {
      ...
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

B.json

```
{
  ...
  ...
  "metadata": {
    ...
    ...
    "ui": {
      "strings": {
        ...
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

From A.json, I grab the **ui** `key`:

```
myVar=$(jq '.ui' A.json)
```

I would like to now replace B's **ui** `key`'s with `myVar`. Can I get assistance with this?

Comment: That's nice, but what's the problem you're having?  If the question is whether it's easy to use jq to accomplish the task, the answer is "yes".

Comment: Not sure how to accomplish it with jq.